# Azure cli - List all webapps where https-only is disabled

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-cli, azure-appservice

I am using azure cli to fetch all the webapps

```
az webapp list --query '[].{Name:name}'
```

It's working fine but I want to query so that it only returns webapps whose "https only" setting is disabled. How can I query that? I tried  `az webapp list --query '[?httpsonly==false].{Name:name}'` but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [query Azure CLI command output using a JMESPath query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli).

> The Azure CLI uses the `--query` argument to execute a JMESPath query on the results of commands. JMESPath is a query language for JSON, giving you the ability to select and modify data from CLI output. Queries are executed on the JSON output before any display formatting.

Since you're looking to filter results, have a look at how you can [filter arrays](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli#filter-arrays).

> The other operation used to get data from an array is *filtering*. Filtering is done with the `[?...]` JMESPath operator. This operator takes a predicate as its contents. A predicate is any statement that can be evaluated to either `true` or `false`. Expressions where the predicate evaluates to `true` are included in the output.

In the end, you were pretty close. The JMESPath already parses booleans, and property names are case sensitive.

This would make the command to list the names of all web apps that have the `httpOnly` property set to false something like this:

`az webapp list --query '[?!httpsOnly].{Name:name}'`

**EDIT:**
Here's an example of the output I get when retrieving all web apps without and with `httpsOnly` set to true respectively from one of my personal tenants:

[image: az cli output]

This seems to show the query works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think there is still something wrong with the query i.e "?!httpsOnly" as I am still getting the web apps whose https only is enabled

Comment: Please have a look at the updated answer, and make sure you have the quotes correct. Also, "When using Azure CLI in PowerShell on Windows, some extra escaping may be necessary for the query argument."

Comment: You're right, I forgot to publish my script. Tried locally and then after publishing and it worked. Thanks

Comment: One other question, is there any list of all the available options to be passed in query? E.g "httpsOnly"?

Comment: Whatever is part of the response can be used in the JMESPath query, since "The Azure CLI uses the --query argument to execute a JMESPath query *on the results of commands*."

Comment: Hi, I've raised another question related to azure-cli. Can you have a look?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71379599/az-webapp-list-is-showing-null-values-for-siteconfig