# az webapp list is showing null values for siteConfig

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell, azure-cli, azure-appservice

I want to get list of all webapps where healhCheckPath is not nult. I tried `az webapp list --query "[?not_null(siteConfig.healthCheckPath)].{Name:name, ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}"` but the cli was returning empty array. I then ran the command `az webapp list --query "[?name=='web_app_where_health_check_is_enabled']"` and this returns one record but heathCheckPath was null but in reality health check is enabled for this specific app.
Later I tried `az webapp show -g <resource-group> -n <name>` and this showed me the value for healthCheckPath. So the issue is with the list command.
I can't use webapp show command because I want to fetch all the webapps which meet specific conditions.

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/21548, my understanding is this is by design, to address performance concerns, the list query doesn't resolve the nested properties,

In that same issue there is a workaround, doing a first list to get the Ids, then do a show command with the list of Ids, I just tried it for a different purpose and works fine

Answer (score 0):

You're using `not_null`, which is a Function that

> Returns the first argument that does not resolve to `null`. This function accepts one or more arguments, and will evaluate them in order until a non null argument is encountered. If all arguments values resolve to `null`, then a value of `null` is returned.

Source: [JMESPath Specification - Built-in Functions - not_null](https://jmespath.org/specification.html#not-null)

For filtering for null values, simply use equality (`==`) or inequality (`!=`).

> #### Comparison Operators
>
> The following operations are supported:
>
> - ==, tests for equality.
> - !=, tests for inequality.
> - <, less than.
> - <=, less than or equal to.
> - >, greater than.
> - >=, greater than or equal to.
>
> The behavior of each operation is dependent on the type of each evaluated expression.
>
> The comparison semantics for each operator are defined below based on the >corresponding JSON type:
>
> #### Equality Operators
>
> For string/number/true/false/null types, equality is an exact match.

Your query translates to
`az webapp list --query "[?siteConfig.healthCheckPath!=null].{Name:name, ResourceGroup:resourceGroup}"`

**EDIT:**
As an addition: this query does seem to do what I understood it needs to: query web apps, returning instances with a non null value for `siteConfig.healthCheckPath`.

Please make sure your scripts have been deployed and no additional filters are in place. See my test-results below.

[image: Query returning results]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this but I'd already tried this but still received empty array

Comment: @Ask see the updated answer.

Comment: so i'm trying to execute it locally it first then I will include this in one of the octopus deploy runbook. But webapp list is not returning expected data while webapp show does

Comment: Did you try adding a healthCheckPath value for any of your instance and then run the same query again?